# Objective-C Alert .. not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, function, alert

For some reason my alert is not working?
If i use `NSLog(@" %@ ", url)` its fine... but no alert here:

```
- (void)alertURL:(NSURL *)url {
UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: url message: @"Error sending your info to the server" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[someError show];
[someError release];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
[self alertURL:url];
return YES;
}
```

Could anyone point out to me whats going wrong :(

Comment: hint: turn up the compiler warnings, and pay attention to them. it makes life much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the NSURL object as the title argument to the UIAlertView initializer.

The `title` argument expects an `NSString` which you clearly are not passing to it.

You need to call `[ url absoluteString ]` or `[ url relativeString ]` instead.